# COM method call accidentally corrupts the stack

Tags: c++, com, stack-smash

I have a bit of code which is calling a method from a COM object (`IDirect3D9`), but every call causes a run-time check failure #0. The failure is caused by ESP not being properly preserved across the call, so some kind of stack issue (as COM methods are all `__stdcall`). The unusual part is the simplicity of the method signature and the circumstances.

The code is built in 32-bit mode only, with MSVC 10 (VS 2010 SP1), using the DirectX SDK (June 2010) headers and libs. I've reinstalled the SDK to make sure the headers weren't corrupt, without luck.

I've run the code with both VS' debugger and WinDBG attached, as well as multiple times after reboots/updated drivers. The problem occurs every time, and is identical. Enabling heap validation (and most other options) in gflags doesn't seem to provide any more information, nor does running with Application Verifier. Both simply report the same error as the popup, or the segfault caused shortly after.

Without the call (returning a constant value instead), the program runs as expected. I'm out of ideas on what could be going wrong here.

The function in question is [`IDirect3D9::GetAdapterModeCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), called from a D3D8-to-9 wrapper (part of [a graphics upgrade project for old games](https://github.com/peachykeen/VoodooShader)). For more general info, [the full file is here](https://github.com/peachykeen/VoodooShader/blob/master/Adapters/Generic/Voodoo_DX89/CVoodoo3D8.cpp).

I've tried all the following forms of the call:

```
UINT r = m_Object->GetAdapterModeCount(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8);

UINT r = m_Object->GetAdapterModeCount(0, (D3DFORMAT)22);

UINT adapter = D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT;
D3DFORMAT format = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8; // and other values
UINT r = m_Object->GetAdapterModecount(adapter, format);
```

All of which cause the check failure. `m_Object` is a valid `IDirect3D9`, and is used previously for a variety of other calls, specifically:

```
201, 80194887, Voodoo3D8, CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterCount() == 3
201, 80195309, Voodoo3D8, CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterIdentifier(0, 2, 0939CBAC) == 0
201, 80195309, Voodoo3D8, CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterDisplayMode(0, 0018F5B4) == 0
201, 80196541, Voodoo3D8, CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterModeCount(0, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8) == 80
```

The sequence is logged by debug trace code, and appears to be correct and returning the expected values (3 monitors and so forth). The first 3 calls, by the same object on my part (a single instance of `CVoodoo3D8`), all succeed with no stack warnings. The fourth does not.

If I reorder the calls, to cause `GetAdapterModeCount` to be called immediately before any of the others in the same object, the same run-time check failure appears. From testing, this seems to rule out an immediately-previous call breaking the stack; the 4 methods calling those 4 functions all occur at different places, and calling `GetAdapterModeCount` anywhere from within this file causes the issue.

Which brings us to the unusual part. A different class (`CVoodoo3D9`) also calls the same sequence of `IDirect3D9` methods, with similar parameters, but does not fail (it is the equivalent wrapper class for D3D9). The objects are not used at the same time (the code picks on or the other depending on the render process I need), but both give the same behavior every time. The code for the other class is held in another file, which led me to suspect preprocessor issues (more on that shortly).

After that didn't provide any information, I examined the calling conventions of my code and parameters. Again, nothing came to light. The codebase compiles with `/w4 /wX` and has for some time, with SAL on most functions and all PREfast rules enabled (and passing).

***In particular**, the call fails when called within this class, whether the call to my method comes from my code or another program using the object. It fails regardless of where it is called, but only within this file.*

The full method is:

```
UINT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterModeCount(UINT Adapter)
{
    UINT r = m_Object->GetAdapterModeCount(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8);

    gpVoodooLogger->LogMessage(LL_Debug, VOODOO_D3D_NAME, Format("CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterModeCount(%d, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8) == %d") << Adapter << r);

    return r;
}
```

*The check failure occurs immediately after the call to `GetAdapterModeCount`* and again as my method returns, if allowed to execute to that point.

The preprocessor output, as given by the preprocess-to-file option, has the method declaration (from `d3d9.h`) correctly as:

```
virtual __declspec(nothrow) UINT __stdcall GetAdapterModeCount( UINT Adapter,D3DFORMAT Format) = 0;
```

The declaration of my method is essentially identical:

```
virtual __declspec(nothrow) UINT __stdcall GetAdapterModeCount(UINT Adapter);
```

My method hardly expands, becoming:

```
UINT __stdcall CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterModeCount(UINT Adapter)
{
    UINT r = m_Object->GetAdapterModeCount(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8);

    gpVoodooLogger->LogMessage(LL_Debug, L"Voodoo3D8", Format("CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterModeCount(%d, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8) == %d") << Adapter << r);

    return r;
}
```

The preprocessor output seems correct for both methods, in the declaration and definition.

The assembly listing up to the point of failure is:

```
    UINT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CVoodoo3D8::GetAdapterModeCount(UINT Adapter)
    {
642385E0  push        ebp  
642385E1  mov         ebp,esp  
642385E3  sub         esp,1Ch  
642385E6  push        ebx  
642385E7  push        esi  
642385E8  push        edi  
642385E9  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
642385EE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax  
642385F1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax  
642385F4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax  
642385F7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
642385FA  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax  
642385FD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
64238600  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax  
        UINT r = m_Object->GetAdapterModeCount(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8);
64238603  mov         esi,esp  
64238605  push        16h  
64238607  push        0  
64238609  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
6423860C  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+8]  
6423860F  mov         edx,dword ptr [this]  
64238612  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+8]  
64238615  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ecx]  
64238617  push        eax  
64238618  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+18h]  
6423861B  call        edx  
6423861D  cmp         esi,esp  
6423861F  call        _RTC_CheckEsp (6424B520h)  
64238624  mov         dword ptr [r],eax
```

*For clarification*, the error comes at `6423861F` (the call to `_RTC_CheckEsp`), suggesting that the call or preparation broke the stack. I am working with the assumption that since the same call works in other places, it is not something within the call breaking things.

To my untrained eye, the only unusual part is the pair of `mov register, dword ptr [register+8]`. As it is a 32-bit system, I'm not sure if `+8` could be incrementing too far, or how it could be getting into the build if so.

Shortly after my method returns, apparently due to the call breaking ESP, the program segfaults. If I don't call `GetAdapterModeCount` and simply return a value, the program executes as expected.

**Additionally**, a release build (no RTC) segfaults at a similar point, with the stack:

```
d3d8.dll!CEnum::EnumAdapterModes()  + 0x13b bytes   
Voodoo_DX89.dll!ClassCreate()  + 0x963 bytes
```

Although I'm not sure of the implications of the address. It is not, so far as I can tell, the same place that segfaults in debug builds; those are within the program after my methods returns, this appears to be during one of my methods which retrieves data from D3D8. **Edit:** The segfault occurs in a later call, which I'm currently debugging.

At this point, I'm at a complete loss as to what is going wrong or how, and am out of things to check.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the call to `gpVoodooLogger->LogMessage`?

Comment: @MSN No change, that call seems to work just fine. The ESP check occurs and fails before it is called, as well. Commenting out the other call does help, but is kind of important.

Comment: There is no good reason the unbalanced ESP value will crash your app.  ESP gets restored by the function epilogue.  I'd just work from the assumption that *both* problems have the same cause, internal program state corruption.

Comment: @HansPassant That seems very reasonable. Two calls to the same interface/object giving issues but others not is unusual. I'm just hoping it was a stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing or with your generated assembly code.

I can answer your one concern, though.

```
ecx,dword ptr [eax+8]
```

What this is doing is moving the address of m_Object into the ecx register. The +8 is the offset within your class to m_Object, which is probably correct.

Something to look at. Step through the assembly code until you reach this point:

```
6423861B  call        edx  
6423861D  cmp         esi,esp
```

At that point check the esi and esp registers (in VS just hover your mouse over the register names).

Before the call is executed, ESI should be 12 higher than ESP. After the call, they should be equal. If they are not, post what they are.

**Update:**

So what is catching my eye is that of the 4 methods you are showing that you are calling, only `GetAdapterModeCount` has a different signature between D3D8 and D3D9, and that signature is different by 4 bytes, which is the difference in your stack.

How is m_Object obtained? Since this is some kind of adapter between D3D8 and D3D9, is it possible that your m_Object is actually an IDirect3D8 object that is being cast as IDirect3D9 at some point? That would explain the error, and why it works in another context, if you are obtaining the D3D object in a different way.

Comment: Hm. Prior to the call, I have ESI at 1635636 and ESP at 1635624 (12 higher, as it should be). However after the call, they are 1635636 and 1635632 respectively. That seems to suggest it actually *is* the call somehow, but the same call works in other code, so I need to figure this out.

Comment: Nice catch. It turned out to be a spot earlier where two `void *`s needed cast to `IDirect3D8*` and `IDirect3D9*`, but the 8 had a typo and was passed later. Now it's crashing in a different, less confusing place. :D